# How to read text from textbox in HTML5 to VB?

Tags: vb.net, html, datepicker

I am using `Microsoft Visual Studio Express` to make a web page.

I used `jQuery`, to create a `date picker` from which I want to choose a date.

I want to read the date into a String in `VB`, so that I can modify it.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
        type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID  %>').datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

In `VB` I have tried:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim temp As String

    temp = TextBox1.value

End Class
```

Why does it not work?

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your example using C# asp.net and with 2 changes i m able to see date...
1. add AutoPostBack="True" in textbox 
2. in .cs use TextBox1.Text (valid for C# not sure of VB)

Comment: I tried your way and it worked out fine. I was about to try something different, like, using a datepicker from VB or something like that. Thanks anyway!